# How to break expression into more lines in Hibernate's import.sql?

Tags: sql, hibernate

In Hibernate there is possibility to add `import.sql` file in root of classpath, and the SQL expressions from this file are executed on database when Hibernate session is created.

However, Hibernate throws exception if some expression is broken into 2 or more lines. How can I break SQL expressions to more lines?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For the sake of someone like me finding this through a search:

If you're using Hibernate4, you can add the following property

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor" value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
```

to your hibernate configuration (mine is JPA's `persistence.xml`).
Compare with the [user manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html) and this [JIRA issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2403).

**Note** that in Hibernate's *hibernate.cfg.xml*, the specification doesn't recognize the `value` attribute and you should provide it as text content:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</property>
```

(thanks Daniel Gerber for pointing this out)

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5-Final an the syntax changed slightly: <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</property>

Comment: I've used this approach and there was a problem with escaped single quotes like `\'`. I had to escape them like `''` and it worked.

Comment: It worked, but in your database, it doesn't appear twice ? I have the same issue, and the single quote is also duplicated in database with `''` in SQL file

Comment: Just lost 2 hours trying to figure out why inserts were silently failing. Why is this not the default! Thanks for this answer.