# Spring jpa spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:create ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

When I used spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and I set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:create and my entity like this

```
@Entity
public class BaseOnDoubleValue extends DoubleData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "uuid",length = 40)
    private long uuid;
    private int baseid;
```

then I got a eror like this

```
2015-11-19 11:07:02.438 ERROR 5876 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table base_on_double_value (uuid bigint generated by default as identity, baseid integer not null, date_time timestamp, error integer not null, id integer not null, quality smallint not null, base_value double, primary key (uuid))
2015-11-19 11:07:02.438 ERROR 5876 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword
```

Can you help me figure it?

Comment: Using [hmb2ddl.auto is the root of all evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673802/how-to-import-initial-data-to-database-with-hibernate/22572463#22572463) ;) You honestly should read that, since you need to understand what happens under the hood and why you should use a proper tool for database change management right away.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I thought it works for me. I want a self-sufficient project that can work in a docker container. I do not want to execute a sql in a container (that means terrible )   And Thank you for give me this suggestion, I will avoid using this on production env.

Comment: Liquibase will be executed from within your application.... During initialization...

Answer (score 2):

I fix this problem by myself.

I add this to application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database= oracle
```