# How to create something in PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, go, crud

I'm learning to use PostgreSQL and GORM. I'm creating a struct, connecting to database, and trying to write in to database.

Source code:

```golang
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres","user=superuser password=ojcafizp123 dbname=gorm sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    database := db.DB()

    err = database.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("Connection to PostgreSQL was successful!")

    port := ":3000"
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Get("/api/test",Test)
    http.ListenAndServe(port, r)
}



func CreateRate (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres","user=superuser password=ojcafizp123 dbname=gorm sslmode=disable")
    cure := Crypto{"BTC","USD",10000,100}
    if db.NewRecord(cure) {
        err = db.Create(&cure).Error
        if err != nil{
            panic(err.Error())

        }
    }
}
```

Struct:

```golang
type Crypto struct {
    Cur1 string `json:"cur1"`
    Cur2 string `json:"cur2"`
    Rate float64 `json:"rate"`
    Timestamp int64 `json:"timestamp"`
}
```

Trying to find my record in the database:

```golang
func Test (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres","user=superuser password=ojcafizp123 dbname=gorm sslmode=disable")
    var testcur Crypto
    db.First(&testcur)
    fmt.Println(testcur)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No testcur detected")
    }

}
```

But got this:

> Connection to PostgreSQL was successful! {  0 0}
>
> (/home/superuser/go/src/CryptoProject/main.go:97)  [2019-07-27
>   05:09:10]  pq: relation "cryptos" does not exist

The connection is working, but the base is still empty.

Comment: Just to add to @khampson's answer, you are nowhere actually calling `CreateRate`, so even if you create the table, without first inserting something into it the `Test` would still fail. And one more thing, the way you handle errors in your `Test` handler is just wrong, first you're ignoring the error returned from `Open`, and then, when you call `First`, instead of checking if that produced an error you check the one returned from `Open`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying that the table `cryptos` does not currently exist, which is why the insert is not working and there's nothing in the database.

I have not previously used *GORM* specifically, but if it's similar to other ORMs, you would need to create a data model representing the table, and then it could create the table using that model. A quick scan of its doc shows *GORM* has a function called [CreateTable](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.CreateTable) that can be called against a [Model](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Model).

You could also create the table outside of *GORM* using regular *SQL* via a tool such as *psql*.

Comment: To expand on this: [using any ORM for database change management is a Very Bad Idea™](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22572463/1296707).

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @khampson, you can use `AutoMigrate` feature:

```
type Product struct {
  gorm.Model
  Code string
  Price uint
}

// Migrate the schema
db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
```

[Full example](https://gorm.io/docs/index.html).