# Entity Framework Core database migration in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

k8s cluster on premises. 3x master, 2x worker nodes.
I need to deploy 5x of my service replicas to my cluster.

Service is an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API, using Entity Framework Core. When the API starts, it updates the database schema.

**Question**: how to deal with migrations when multiple instances are starting? I have read about init containers and leader election, but not sure it is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned init containers and leader election as potential solutions. An effective approach would combine the use of **[Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)** in Kubernetes with a **[lock mechanism](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/leases/)** to make sure only one pod performs the migration at a time.
That can be achieved through various locking mechanisms, such as using a distributed lock with a database, a Redis lock, or leveraging Kubernetes resources like ConfigMaps or Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs) to implement the lock.

Try and define an init container in your pod's specification that runs before your application containers start. That init container should execute the migration script.

Something like this, assuming you have a migration script and a way to acquire and release a lock:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: your-api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: migration-init-container
        image: your-migration-image
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "<your-migration-command>"]
      containers:
      - name: your-api-container
        image: your-api-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Replace `<your-migration-command>` with the actual command to run your migrations, including any logic necessary to acquire and release the lock.

Implement a locking mechanism to make sure only one init container can perform migrations at any time. One approach is using a shared resource that can be locked, such as a row in your database or a dedicated ConfigMap in Kubernetes.

The init container tries to acquire the lock. If successful, it performs the migration. After completion, it releases the lock. If it cannot acquire the lock (because another instance has already acquired it), it waits or terminates, allowing the main application container to start.

Once the init container has finished running (either by completing the migration or detecting that another instance has done it), your application container can start normally.

---

> I thought this way, but this means I should move the database migration logic to separate project, build an image for it and only then setup the init container.

True, but you get as advantages:

- By isolating the migration logic into its own project and Docker image, you enhance the modularity and maintainability of your system. That separation makes it easier to manage versioning and dependencies of the migration logic independently of the main application.
- Having a dedicated migration image gives you more control over when and how migrations are executed, as you can update and deploy this image separately from the rest of your application stack.
- That allows the migration image to be reused across different environments (development, testing, production) and even across different projects that may share the same database schema.

If you need alternative approaches/options:

- Instead of moving the migration logic to a separate project, you can keep it within your main application but control its execution through environment variables or configuration files.
  The application can check these configurations at startup and decide whether to run the migration logic.
  That would eliminate the need for a separate migration project but requires careful handling of the application's startup sequence.
- Or: Instead of using an init container, consider deploying a Kubernetes Job or CronJob to handle migrations. That can be configured to run before updating the application deployments. Jobs are designed for tasks like migrations and provide features like retries and logging.
  That still benefits from a separate migration logic but does not require it to be part of the application's normal startup process.
- In some cases, especially when migrations are significant or need close supervision, running migrations manually as a step before deployment may be preferable. That can be done via CI/CD pipelines or directly through command line tools, providing maximum control over the migration process.

---

> I see there are several ways, and I am asking for best practices.
>
> In Dotnet's entity framework, we just inject the database and run 'migrate'. It runs through the schema and updates it. No custom logic is needed.
>
> - My first decision was to move migration logic to another image and configure initContainer.
> - Second, just migrate through CLI.
>
> I am not sure if it is good to handle it through the environment, if the application starts receiving data, but the first pod won't finish with migration, it will fail.
>
> As for features of entity framework, I think k8s Job or CronJob are also not suitable.

The main concern is making sure a smooth, reliable process that minimizes downtime and prevents issues when multiple instances of a service are starting simultaneously.
You might consider two best practices:

1. **Init Container for Exclusive Migration Execution**: The initial idea of using an init container is solid, especially for EF Core applications. That method makes sure migrations are applied *before* any application containers within the pod start.
   To address the concern about separating migration logic into another image:

   - **Pros**: Isolation of migration logic, which can be beneficial for managing dependencies and making sure that the migration environment is controlled and consistent.
   - **Cons**: Additional overhead in managing multiple Docker images and making sure that the migration image is updated in sync with the application's EF Core model changes.
2. **Single Application Image with Migration Command Execution**: An alternative to separating the migration logic into a different image is to include the migration execution as part of the application's *startup* process, controlled by an environment variable or command-line argument. That simplifies deployment by using a single image but requires careful management to make sure migrations are executed only once and successfully before other instances start serving traffic.
   You would do that by:

   - Implementing a **lock mechanism** (using a database lock, a distributed lock system like Redis, or Kubernetes primitives) makes sure only one instance proceeds with the migration at a time.
   - coupling it with **readiness probes** in Kubernetes to delay traffic routing to the pods until they are fully ready (i.e., after migrations have been successfully applied).

To mitigate the risk of the application starting and receiving data before migration completion, consider using:

- **Graceful Startup**: Enhance the application's startup logic to check if migrations are pending or in progress, and delay full initialization (including serving traffic) until migrations are completed. That can be achieved through custom health checks or startup delays.
- **Database Readiness Check**: Implement a readiness check in your application that verifies the database schema is up-to-date before starting to serve traffic. That can be a simple query that checks for the existence of a specific table or schema version.

---

[Markus W. Mahlberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296707/markus-w-mahlberg) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77978662/entity-framework-core-database-migration-in-kubernetes/78004464?noredirect=1#comment137566566_78004464):

> Any DBCMS worth its salt should be aware of its state, most of the ones I know will use the DBMS. As far as I understand, in this case the ORM does the migration.

Markus references his [2014 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22572463/6309).

That means it is important to recognize the inherent limitations when relying only on ORM tools like Entity Framework Core for database migrations, especially in complex environments like Kubernetes.

Markus's commentary, drawn from experiences in the Java ecosystem, underscores similar limitations applicable to .NET's Entity Framework:

- **Risk of Data Loss**: Auto-generated migrations may not adequately safeguard existing data or handle the nuances of complex schema changes, potentially leading to data loss or corruption.
- **Lack of Transaction Support**: Without transactional safeguards, migrations might leave the database in an inconsistent state should an error occur during the process.
- **Reduced Control and Transparency**: Relying on automatic migrations diminishes the visibility and control developers have over the changes applied to the database schema, which could lead to unintended outcomes.
- **Assumptions in Testing**: Presuming that test and production databases are in identical states without thorough verification introduces risks, as any discrepancies could have significant repercussions.

Hence the need of best practices to mitigate risks while utilizing EF Core within Kubernetes.
Drawing from Markus's approach and broader database management best practices, you might consider:

- **Manual Review of Migrations** generated by EF Core before application, making sure alignment with intended schema changes and safeguarding against potential data risks.
- **Database Version Control**, using database version control tools, such as [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/), in conjunction with EF Core: it provides finer control over database changes. These tools facilitate rollback capabilities and support more complex migration scenarios.
- **Integration with CI/CD Pipelines**, incorporating database migration processes: it enables automated testing against production database copies, helping to identify and resolve issues early in the deployment cycle.
- **Using Kubernetes Jobs for Controlled Migration Execution**: Despite reservations about Kubernetes Jobs and CronJobs for migrations, they can be effectively employed if integrated with the aforementioned best practices. Kubernetes Jobs can manage a controlled migration process—reviewing, testing, and applying migrations via version control tools to make sure environmental consistency.

You would need a balanced approach, leveraging the strengths of EF Core for development and prototyping, while integrating robust database change management practices.
This is important for production deployments. It will help not only with the consistency and integrity of database schemas across multiple service instances, but also with minimizing downtime and operational risks.

Comment: Just found https://github.com/coderanger/migrations-operator mentioned in  [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/x5p9gm/database_migration_when_your_service_is_running/): it could be of interest too.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought this way, but this means I should move the database migration logic to separate project, build an image for it and only then setup the init container.

Comment: Thanks again! I see there are several ways and I am asking for a best practices. 
In dotnet's entity framework we just inject database and run 'migrate'. It runs through the schema and updates it. None custom logic is needed.
My first decision was to move migration logic to another image and configure initContainer.
Second just migrate through cli. 
Not sure it is good to handle it through environment, if application will start receiving data but first pod won't finish with migration, it will fail. 
As of features of entity framework I think k8s Job or CronJob are also not suitable.

Comment: My 2 cents to this excellent answer: Any DBCMS worth its salt should be aware of its state, most of the ones I know will use the DBMS. As far as I understand, in this case the ORM does the migration. In this case, [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673802/how-to-import-initial-data-to-database-with-hibernate/22572463#22572463) (though for the Java ecosystem, but the principles apply here, too) might shed some light on why that is a Very Bad Idea™ to begin with.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as some additional considerations. Let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: I think I will end up with additional pipeline stage,  cloning my repo and migrating the schema with dotnet cli.

Comment: @arturas Good call, that should work.

Comment: @VonC You nailed it. Especially the application of the principles in the  Kubernetes ecosystem.